# Save current file and open another for editing

Tags: command-line, multiple-files, file-operations

Is there a way to effectively combine `:w` and `:e` commands so that the current file is saved and a new one is opened for editing in one go? And to do so in a way that allows tab completion of path and filename on the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`command`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acommand) to add new commands. These have to start with a capital letter.

Something like this should do what you want:

```
command! -nargs=1 -complete=file WE write | edit <args>
```

You can then do:

```
:WE new-file
```

- `-nargs=1` -  accept one argument
- `-complete=file` - do file completion
- `WE` - the command name
- `write | edit <args>` - first call `:w`, and then `:e` with the argument we gave it.

---

Note that there's also the [`autowrite`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27noaw%27) option:

> Write the contents of the file, if it has been modified, on each
>   `:next`, `:rewind`, `:last`, `:first`, `:previous`, `:stop`, `:suspend`, `:tag`, `:!`,
>   `:make`, `CTRL-]` and `CTRL-^` command; and when a `:buffer`, `CTRL-O`, `CTRL-I`,
>   `'{A-Z0-9}`, or `` `{A-Z0-9} `` command takes one to another file.

and the [`autowriteall`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27noawa%27) option:

> Like `'autowrite'`, but also used for commands `:edit`, `:enew`, `:quit`,
>   `:qall`, `:exit`, `:xit`, `:recover` and closing the Vim window.
>   Setting this option also implies that Vim behaves like `'autowrite'` has
>   been set.